# Moving Boxes jquery plugin variable widths

Tags: jquery, slider

I'm looking at using http://css-tricks.com/moving-boxes/ jquery plugin.
Can someone please tell me if its possible to make it handle variable-width panels?

I need an image slider/carousel that centres the current image and shows half the prev and next images. Moving boxes is great and almost fits the bill just need variable width images that still slide to the centre.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that is possible, adjust the width in div .inside and .img in your HTML for the actual size of your images, and delete the line in the CSS that will re-assign the width during the slide.  You can do this by inspecting the elements and editing them in the browser while viewing the Demo.

edit the CSS and HTML , and in addition the img size and container size is set in jQuery , this is on the top of the slider.js

```
        var totalPanels         = $(".scrollContainer").children().size();

var regWidth            = $(".panel").css("width");
var regImgWidth         = $(".panel img").css("width");
var regTitleSize        = $(".panel h2").css("font-size");
var regParSize          = $(".panel p").css("font-size");

var movingDistance      = 300;

var curWidth            = 350;
var curImgWidth         = 326;
var curTitleSize        = "20px";
var curParSize          = "15px";
```

Try deleting / editing these values as needed

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for your help. I have tried removing all width styles and putting the width on the actual img tag in the HTML, but when it loads it takes the width of the first element and sets all the widths to that. any ideas?

Comment: Thanks so much scott I'll give this a go when I get the chance. cheers mate